# Editing an AAD invited user with MSFT Graph

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I've been messing with this for a while and I'm missing something obvious.

I've got a bunch of invited guests in Azure AD. I'm trying to update some of their details (specifically the Company name). At this point, I've resorted to basically copying the sample from Microsoft and it's still not working for me.

Is it possible that you can't edit user info for an invited guest?

Or, is it me:

```
var savedUser = await graphClient
  .Users[strUid]
  .Request()
  .GetAsync();

var user = new User
{
  BusinessPhones = new List<string>()
  {
  "+61 123 456 789"
  },
  OfficeLocation = "Brisbane"
};

var updated = await graphClient
  .Users[savedUser.Id]
  .Request()
  .UpdateAsync(user);
```

I appreciate any thoughts, suggestions, abuse.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

> Code: Request_BadRequest Message: One or more property values specified are invalid.

Please check your properties of user whether in the [Request Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request-body).

---

I tried the following code with the required application permissions, and it worked well.

```
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithTenantId(tenantID)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var user = new User
{
    BusinessPhones = new List<String>()
    {
        "+61 123 456 789"
    },
    OfficeLocation = "Brisbane"
};

await graphClient.Users["user-object-id"]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(user);
```

[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Hi Pamela, thanks for your efforts. I think my issue may be a missing API permission. I'll have to play around with it but with your help I know it's doable. (You'd think that user readwrite all would've done it). Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note the following from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

> Updating another user's `businessPhones`, `mobilePhone`, or `otherMails` property is only allowed on users who are non-administrators.

If the `strUid` represents an Admin, you cannot update `businessPhones` for that user.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts Marc. Nope, not an admin. I think I'm missing an API permission. Appreciate your time though.